# How to fix "peewee.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: fiskalna.user_id"

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am trying to make my first web app with Flask but when I run it I get an error: peewee.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: fiskalna.user_id

Can someone help me?

I have searched everywhere even here there is a similar question but it did't solved my problem. If there is a problem regarding my question, please excuse me I am still beginner.

models.py

```py
            raise ValueError("User exsists")
class Fiskalna(Model):
    user=ForeignKeyField(
        model=User,
        backref='fiskalna')
    br_fiskalna=IntegerField(unique=True)
    suma=IntegerField()
    dnaok=FloatField()
    dodanena_na=DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    class Meta():
        database=DATABASE
        order_by=("-dodanena_na")
```

app.py

```py
@app.route("/new", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def post():
    form=forms.FiskalnaForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        models.Fiskalna.create(
                               br_fiskalna=form.br_fiskalna.data,
                               suma=form.suma.data,
                               danok=form.danok.data)
        flash("Postiranoo", "success")
        return redirect(url_for("register"))
    return render_template("post.html", form=form)
```

Comment: it seems you have wrong data in database. Your database has NULL in user_id but it is not allowed - and you get error message for this. Open database in any database's editor/viewer and check your data - ie. [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) OR delete database and create it from scratch again - and don't add data without user_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know too much about Peewee, but I can see you have declared a `ForeignKeyField` "User", which you haven't populated in your `.create(...` call.

I'm assuming in the database, the ForeignKeyField results in a NOT NULL column being created on the `fiskalna` table - `user_id`, which is what is giving the IntegrityError.

To solve, when you want to add a new `Fiskalna` record, you'll need to include `user=your_user_record` in the `create()` call.

Sidenote, you also have a typo in create on the `danok` parameter - it doesn't match the model column.